# Does YouTube support speed control on the Mobile Site (m.youtube.com)?

Tags: youtube, video, mobile, video-streaming

YouTube provides a mobile site however, no matter what I set my UserAgent to be I never get the HTML5 media player with speed controls,

For example, set your UserAgent to `Mozilla / 5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Redmi Note 4) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, como Gecko) Chrome / 70.0.3538.80 Mobile Safari / 537.36`

Then go to `m.youtube.com` hit up a movie.

Is there anyway to get speed controls on the mobile YouTube site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is no longer relevant. Youtube mobile supports playback speed adjustment

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your browser supports extensions/addons, you can probably take any of the many HTML5 video speed controller extensions/addons.